# write sql query to discard numeric decimal(25.0987)values with some string and keep those values who are not rounded(25)

Tags: sql, oracle

In some source table suppose a column there

```
Column A
25.00
19.890
16
5.980
100
```

Write sql to show output

```
Column A
25,
Decimal values so discarded,
16,
Decimal values so discarded,
100,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT COLUMNA FROM SOURCE WHERE TRUNC(COLUMNA) <> COLUMNA;
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=488df32468cc55939a07878c392d9e07)

Cheers!!